# Regex everything before (-) if matches 7 characters

Tags: regex

Good morning,

Could tou please help on this regular expression request.

I would like all characters before `"-"`, but only if that chain has a lenght of 7 characters

If `5QHTN33-48314742`, result `5QHTN33`. But if `AAA5QHTN33-48314742`, then no result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Multiple ways I'd say, but you could give `^[A-Z\d]{7}(?=-\d+$)` a go, or more generic `^([^-]{7})-.*$`. What have you come up with yourself?

Answer (score -2):

as  `'^'` refers to start of line and `'$'` refers to end of line, I highly prefer to say you have to split the line with spaces(regex of split: `(\s+)` , for java: `(\\s+)`) so you can use below regex after splitting and use it on every element, hope to be helpful:

```
(^)((?<word>[\w\W]{7})\-.+)($)
```

**Explanation**

`(?<word>[\w\W]{7})` will capture your word into a group with name `word` ,so you can get it easier.